# How to unlink a Roku application on uninstall?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm trying to get my application to automatically unlink itself from the server when the user uninstalls it from their Roku.

The [Roku documentation](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Device+Registration+And+Linking) recommends sending a token to the client app on activation which the Roku can use for subsequent operations (like streaming media) on the server.  The idea is that if the user uninstalls the app, the token will be lost, effectively decoupling the client from the server.

This approach seems somehow messy, though, seeing as how numerous uninstallations will cause the server to have a lot of useless tokens lying around.

Is there another approach to unlinking the application when the user uninstalls it?  Does Brightscript perhaps have a callback that fires when the user uninstalls the app, so I can manually call an endpoint on my server to deactivate it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Roku apps don't have any on notification on uninstall or opportunity to execute code at such a point in time, as far as I know. I think you're out of luck.

With regards to alternative solutions to stacking up many useless tokens, perhaps work with an expiration time? For instance, invalidating and removing any token that haven't seen any activity for a few months? This would be annoying though to users who simply haven't used the app, but haven't uninstalled, when they start the app after a long time and have to log in again.